# ReactJs production build: Getting 404 not found errors on page refresh even with htaccess catch all configured

Tags: reactjs, apache

I have deployed a reactjs application to apache server which is also hosting django. The application is working ok unless on page refresh when it redirects to django with `Page not found (404)` error. Now i am struggling to fix this as i have followed all the directives i have found elsewhere on this site as follows.

I have added `htaccess` to the folder where `index.html` resides as follows

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is how i a have configured my routing on react

```
 <div className="App">
        <BrowserRouter basename={``}>
          <ScrollContext>
            <Switch>
              <Route
                path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/login`}
                component={LoginForm}
              />
              <Route
                path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/invoices/:bookingId`}
                component={Invoice}
              ></Route>
//more code
```

and here is `package.json` config

```
{
  "name": "marvellous-ventures-admin",
  "homepage": "https://marvellousventures.com/dashboard",
  "version": "0.1.0",
```

Will anyone please help me fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

After spending ridiculously large amount of time on this, i finally figured out where the issue was and oh my do i feel stupid. As you can see on my question there's preceding forward slash which was causing me issues as you can see here.`RewriteRule . /index.html [L]` I have removed the forward slash and my application is able to refresh without throwing an error.